# Create a function middle()that returns the middle character/s of a word. If a word has even number of characters, return the middle two characters

Tags: javascript, string

```js
var str = ""
var position
var length

function middle(str) {
  if ((str % 2) == 0) {
    position = str.length / 2;
    length = 2;
  } else {
    position = (str.length + 1) / 2;
    length = 1;
  }

  return str.substring(position, position + length);
}

middle("mynameis")
```

[So here is my question, thank you in advance!](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/iodized-dedication?path=index.html:39:8)

It just doesn't return anything. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: "It just doesn't return anything" ....how do you know? Your code is trying to read the returned value. Try `alert(middle("mynameis"))` as a simple test to show the output

Comment: Thanks for the input: ) when I try alert it works, however when I call the function it doesn't show anything in the new tab. Do you happen to know why? Thanks!

Comment: What new tab are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that need to change:

1. Unless you're just typing this into the console, nothing will display anywhere,
   so I put the function calls in a `console.log()` statement.
2. In your `if` statement, you need `str.length` instead of `str`.
3. JavaScript string (and array) methods are [zero-based](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp), meaning the first
   character of a string is at index `0` as opposed to `1` as you might guess from
   the word "first." Because of this, I changed 
   `position = str.length / 2` to `position = str.length / 2 - 1` and
   `position = (str.length + 1) / 2` to `position = (str.length - 1) / 2`.
4. (Not mandatory) Try to no use unnecessary global variables. Unless you
   need to use `str`, `position`, or `length` somewhere else in the program,
   put their declarations inside the function. In fact, the `str` variable
   will not be used or changed by the function at all because `str` is the
   name of a parameter of the function.

The code in the snippet below implements these changes.

```js
function middle(str) {
  var position, length;
  if ((str.length % 2) == 0) {
    position = str.length / 2 - 1;
    length = 2;
  } else {
    position = (str.length - 1) / 2;
    length = 1;
  }
  
  return str.substring(position, position + length);
}

console.log(middle("mynameis")); // am
console.log(middle("abc")); // b
console.log(middle("abcd")); // bc
```

Comment: But why is the length=2, not 1 in the if statement tho? When I think about it again, you only need to add 1 one number so the length should be equal to 1? (e.g. abcd, the position of c is just one more than b.)

Comment: Yeah now I get it. I misunderstood the definition of substring.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most understandable solution will be. No magic) All you need - understand substring and length method.

```
 function Middle(str){
   let a; // define new variable, we will use it to return new string with character
   if (str.length % 2 === 0) {
    a = str.substring(str.length/2-1, str.length/2 + 1)
   } else {
     a = str.substring(str.length/2, str.length/2 + 1) 
   }
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function Middle(str) {
        let p;
        if(str.length % 2 == 1) {
            p = str.length / 2;
            return str.substring(p, p + 1)
        } 
        p = str.length / 2 - 1;
        return str.substring(p, p + 2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however I have not learnt the let statement. Still appreciate tho.

Comment: In addition to providing an example, you should include a description of what your code does.